# calculating the gradient of a particular multivariate normal

Tags: derivatives, matrix-calculus

Suppose I have negative twice a log-likelihood of some multivariate normal data: $x_1, \ldots, x_n$. I assume the covariance matrix has a low-rank structure: $LL^\intercal + \Psi$, where $\Psi$ is diagonal, and $L$ is lower-triangular and low rank. The mean vector is $\mu$.

\begin{align}
f(\mu, L, \Psi) &= - 2 \log L(x_1, \ldots, x_n ; \mu, L, \Psi)\\
&= \text{const} + n\log \det(LL^\intercal + \Psi) + \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \mu)^\intercal  (LL^\intercal + \Psi)^{-1} (x_i - \mu) \\
&= \text{const} + n\log \det(LL^\intercal + \Psi) + \text{trace}\left[ (LL^\intercal + \Psi)^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^n    (x_i - \mu)(x_i - \mu)^\intercal\right] 
\end{align}

I assume that because these matrices lie on a lower-dimensional space, the gradient can be written as

\begin{align*}
\nabla f(\mu, L, \Psi) 
&= \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial \mu} \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial \text{vech} (L)} \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial \text{diag} (\Psi)}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

Finding the first block of that vector is straightforward:

\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial \mu} 
&=  - 2  (LL^\intercal + \Psi)^{-1}n \bar{x} + 2 n (LL^\intercal + \Psi)^{-1}\mu
\end{align*}

However, I'm stuck on the other two pieces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$
\def\bs{\boldsymbol}
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\P{{\Psi}}
\def\M{P^{-1}}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\vecc#1{\op{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\vech#1{\op{vech}\LR{#1}}
\def\diag#1{\op{diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\op{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\qif{\quad\iff\quad}
\def\p{\partial}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
\def\Sk{\sum_{k=1}^n}
$For typing convenience, define the *all-ones* vector $\o$ and the variables
$$\eqalign{
P &= {\P+LL^T} \\
dP &= d\P+dL\,L^T+L\,dL^T \\
p &= \diag{\P} \qif \P = \Diag{p} \\
h &= \vech{L} = {Ev} \\
v &= \vecc{L} \:= \c{E^Th} \\
}$$
where $E$ is the [Elimination Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duplication_and_elimination_matrices#Elimination_matrix) and the last equality
in $\c{\rm red}$ is only true if $L$ is lower triangular.

Replace the vector summation by a matrix whose columns are the {$x_k$} vectors
$$\eqalign{
X &= {\bs[}\,x_1\;x_2\:\cdots\:x_n\,{\bs]} \\
M &= {\bs[}\;\mu\;\;\mu\;\;\cdots\;\;\mu\,{\bs]} \;= \mu\o^T \\
Y &= {M-X} \qiq dY = d\mu\,\o^T \\
Z &= \M Y \\
YY^T &= \Sk \LR{x_k-\mu}\LR{x_k-\mu}^T  \\
}$$
and introduce the Frobenius product, which is a concise
notation for the trace
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
A:A &= \|A\|^2_F \\
}$$
The properties of the underlying trace function allow the terms in a
Frobenius product to be rearranged in many different ways, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= B:A \;=\; \vecc{A}:\vecc{B} \\
A:B &= A^T:B^T \\
C:\LR{AB} &= \LR{CB^T}:A = \LR{A^TC}:B \\
\Diag{a}:B &= a:\diag{B} \\
\\
}$$

---

Write the function using the above notation, then calculate its differential
$$\eqalign{
f &= f_0 + n\log\det(P) + YY^T:\M \\
\\
df
 &= n\,d\LR{\log\det P} + YY^T:{d\M} + \M:d\LR{YY^T} \\
 &= n\LR{P^{-1}:dP} 
   \;+\; YY^T:\LR{-\M\,dP\,\M}
   \;+\; \M:\LR{dY\,Y^T+Y\,dY^T} \\
 &= nP^{-1}:\c{dP} \;-\; ZZ^T:\c{dP} \;+\; 2\M Y:dY \\
 &= \LR{nP^{-1}-ZZ^T}:\CLR{d\P+dL\,L^T+L\,dL^T}
   \;+\; 2\M Y:\LR{d\mu\,\o^T} \\
 &= \LR{nP^{-1}-ZZ^T}:d\P
   \;+\; 2\LR{nP^{-1}-ZZ^T}L:dL
   \;+\; 2\M Y\o:d\mu \\
 &= \diag{nP^{-1}-ZZ^T}:dp
   \;+\; 2\vecc{nP^{-1}L-ZZ^TL}:dv
   \;+\; 2\M Y\o:d\mu \\
\\
 &= \diag{nP^{-1}-ZZ^T}:dp
   \;+\; 2\vecc{nP^{-1}L-ZZ^TL}:E^Tdh
   \;+\; 2\M Y\o:d\mu \\
 &= \diag{nP^{-1}-ZZ^T}:dp
   \;+\; 2E\,\vecc{nP^{-1}L-ZZ^TL}:dh
   \;+\; 2\M Y\o:d\mu \\
}$$
Now isolate the respective gradients as
$$\eqalign{
\grad{f}{p} &= \diag{nP^{-1}-ZZ^T} \\
\grad{f}{v} &= 2\vecc{nP^{-1}L-ZZ^TL} \\
\grad{f}{h} &= 2E\,\vecc{nP^{-1}L-ZZ^TL} \\
\grad{f}{\mu} &= 2\M Y\o \\
}$$
Note that
$$E\,\vecc{nP^{-1}L-ZZ^TL}\ne\vech{nP^{-1}L-ZZ^TL}$$
because the matrix argument is not symmetric.

Comment: @Taylor I updated the answer for the `vech` case

Comment: what if $L$ isn't square but tall and skinny?

Comment: How would you define `vech(L)` in that case?

Comment: :) Take an identity and remove all the rows that correspond to zeros in the $\text{vec}$'d out matrix. Not sure which formulas no longer work only apply to square matrices, but I'll poke around this book that everyone seems to keep citing. Thanks for the help

Comment: I see. Then multiply the gradient by that reduced identity and you're done
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial h_r}= I_r\cdot\frac{\partial f}{\partial h}$$
and the reduced _skinny_ triangle is $\,L_r=L\cdot I_r\quad$